# Creating a cookie in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I'm trying to create code that will write two cookies to the user computer.
The first cookie that I'm trying to create is a cookie named ‘customername’. This will store the name of the customer when the order form is processed. The cookie should be valid for 365 days.

The first cookie that I'm trying to create is a cookie named ‘lastvisit’ and it stores the date/time when the page was last visited.

When the page loads it will check if the cookies exist. If they do not exist, print at the top of the page: “Welcome New Customer!” If they do exist, read the cookie data and print at top of the page:  “Welcome back ‘customername’. Your last visit was ‘lastvisit’ ”.

This is what I have for my javascript and html.
I know I need to check local storage to check if cookies exist.
However, I'm having hard time creating functional cookies and checking cookies if it exist.

```js
/*index.js*/
window.onload=initfunction;

function initfunction()

{

 var toDay = new Date(); 

  

 document.getElementById("datefield").innerHTML = toDay;

}



function buttonandchecks()

{

 //this will use a 'for' loop to check the radio buttons and

 //a series of 'if' statements to verify the check boxes

 var x;

 var message="";
   var pizzaLine;
 var pizzaType;
 var pizzaSize;
 var pizzaPrice; 
               
 var sandwichLine;
 var samdwichsplit;
 var sandwichType;
 var sandwichPrice;
               
 var sodaLine;
 var sodaSplit;
 var sodaSize;
 var sodaPrice;
 var drink;
 

 var pizzaresultmessage="";
 var toppingresultmessage="";
 var totalresultmessage="";
 var sandwichresultmessage="";
 var sodaresultmessage="";
 var nameresultmessage=document.getElementById("name").value;
 var addressresultmessage=document.getElementById("address").value;
 var phoneresultmessage=document.getElementById("phone").value;
       

    var giftamount=parseFloat(0);
    var orderamount=parseFloat(0);
    var sodaorderamount=parseFloat(0);
    
    var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    var sandwichquantity = document.getElementById("sandwichquantity").value;
    var sodaquantity = document.getElementById("sodaquantity").value;

    
    var radio_value; //get value from radio button
    var sandwich_value;
    var soda_value;
 
 var sodatype_value;
 

 var totalvaluepizza=parseInt(0); //initialize this to 0
 var finalcost=parseInt(0);
 
 

 quantity = parseFloat(quantity);
 sandwichquantity = parseFloat(sandwichquantity);
 sodaquantity = parseFloat(sodaquantity); //use query selector-specialty is the radio button type
 

 
 ////////////Trial new ways//////////////////////////
  
 
 pizzaLine=document.querySelector('input[name=specialty]:checked').value;
 pizzaType=pizzaLine.split(":");
 pizzaSize=p.Type[0];
 pizzaPrice=p.Type[1];
 //parse pizzaPrice into Float to calculate Total Cost
 pizzaPrice=parseFloat(pizzaPrice);
 
 TypePizza=document.querySelector('input[name=pizzatype]:checked').value;
 
 
 
 sandwichLine=document.querySelector('input[name=sandwichtype]:checked').value;
 sandwichSplit=sandwichLine.split(":");
 sandwichType=sandwichSplit[0];
 sandwichPrice=sandwichSplit[1];
 sandwichPrice=parseFloat(sandwichPrice);

 sodaLine=document.querySelector('input[name=drinkspecialty]:checked').value;
 sodaSplit=sodaLine.split(":");
 sodaSize=sodaSplit[0];
 sodaPrice=sodaSplit[1]; 
 sodaPrice=parseFloat(sodaPrice);
 
 sodaType=document.querySelector('input[name=sodatype]:checked').value;
 

 //parse radio_value to a float

 radio_value=parseFloat(radio_value);



 //if statements to get the values from the check boxes

 if(document.querySelector('input[name=extracheese]:checked'))

  {

  //giftamount+=100;//the giftamount will by increased by this value, in this case 100
  //vital: you must use parseFloat to convert the values from the check boxes to number amounts
  giftamount+=parseFloat(document.querySelector('input[name=cheese]:checked').value);

  message=(message+"cheese ");

  }

 if(document.querySelector('input[name=pepperoni]:checked'))

  {

  //giftamount+=150;
  giftamount+=parseFloat(document.querySelector('input[name=pepperoni]:checked').value);
  

  message=(message+" Pepperoni ");

  }

 if(document.querySelector('input[name=mushroom]:checked'))

  {

  //giftamount+=175;
  giftamount+=parseFloat(document.querySelector('input[name=mushroom]:checked').value);

  message=(message+" Mushroom ");

  }

 if(document.querySelector('input[name=bacon]:checked'))

  {

  //giftamount+=200;
  giftamount+=parseFloat(document.querySelector('input[name=bacon]:checked').value);

  message=(message+" Bacon ");

  }
 if(document.querySelector('input[name=olives]:checked'))

  {

  //giftamount+=200;
  giftamount+=parseFloat(document.querySelector('input[name=olives]:checked').value);

  message=(message+" Olives ");

  }
  
  

 //calculate total cost of gift

 totalvaluepizza=pizzaPrice+giftamount;

 finalcost=quantity*(pizzaPrice+giftamount)+sandwichquantity*sandwichPrice+sodaquantity*sodaPrice;

      

 pizzaresultmessage=(quantity+"  "+ pizzaSize + " " + TypePizza + " Pizza "+"  $ "+ quantity*pizzaPrice);
 toppingresultmessage=("Extra:  "+message+giftamount.toFixed(2));
 

 totalresultmessage=("Total Cost for Pizza+Sandwich+soda:  $ "+finalcost.toFixed(2));
 sandwichresultmessage=(sandwichquantity+"  "+ sandwichType+" $ " + sandwichquantity*sandwichPrice.toFixed(2));
 sodaresultmessage=(sodaquantity+" "+ sodaSize + drink + " $ " +sodaquantity*sodaPrice.toFixed(2));  
  
 

 //Customer input message displayed sections
 document.getElementById("showname").innerHTML=nameresultmessage;
 document.getElementById("showaddress").innerHTML=addressresultmessage;
 document.getElementById("showtel").innerHTML=phoneresultmessage;


 document.getElementById("showpizza").innerHTML=pizzaresultmessage;
 document.getElementById("showtopping").innerHTML=toppingresultmessage;
 document.getElementById("showtotal").innerHTML=totalresultmessage;
   
 document.getElementById("showsandwich").innerHTML=sandwichresultmessage;
 document.getElementById("showsoda").innerHTML=sodaresultmessage;

   

   

}

//usercookie.js

$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $("#submit").click(function() {
  
  var username = $("#customername").val();
  var userid = $("#lastvisit").val();
 
 $.cookie('customername’', customername,{expires:365});
 $.cookie('lastvisit’ ', lastvisit,{expires:365});
 //display cookies values
 $("#showcookies").html("Your cookies are: "+$.cookie('customername') + " and " + $.cookie('lastvisit') );


});

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="author" content="791894" >
<meta name="date" content="2019-03-15T22:37:02-0700" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="City Delicatessen.js"></script>
<link href="PartA.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter|Open+Sans|Slabo+27px" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/PartA.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Today is: <span id="dtfield" ></span></h1>
<br>
<br>


<div id="background">
<br>
<h1>Welcome to City Delicatessen </h1>
<div id="contents">

<table cellpadding="5" class="formtable">
<form name="information">
<tr><td>&#183;   First and Last Name :&nbsp;</td><td><input type="text" id="name" size="25" maxlength="25" autofocus="yes" pattern="[a-zA-Z]| |-|*$"></td></tr>
<tr><td>&#183;   Street Address :&nbsp;</td><td><input type="text" id="address" size="25" maxlength="25" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]| |/|,|.|\|@|#|$|%|&)+"></td></tr>
<tr><td>&#183;   Phone Number :&nbsp;</td><td><input type="tel" size="25" id="phone" placeholder="XXX XXX XXXX" pattern="\d{3} \d{3} \d{4}"></td></tr>
</form>
</table>
<br><br>

<form name=order>
<table style="width:100%">

<tr valign=top>
<td>
<b>Choose Pizza <b><br>
  <img src="cheesepizza.jpg" alt="Forest">
<input type=radio name=pizzatype value=0.00 checked>Super Cheesy<br>
  <img src="meatpizza.jpg" alt="Forest">
<input type=radio name=pizzatype  value=0.00 >Extra Meaty<br>
  <img src="veggypizza.jpg" alt="Forest">
<input type=radio name=pizzatype  value=0.00 >Really Veggy<br>
</td>
</table>
<br>
<table>
<td>
<b>Choose Size <b><br>
<input type=radio name=specialty value=8.50 checked >Small: $8.50<br>
<input type=radio name=specialty value=11.50>Medium: $11.50<br>
<input type=radio name=specialty value=14.00>Large: $14.00<br>
<input type=radio name=specialty value=16.50>Extra Large: $16.50<br>
</td>
</table>

<table>
<br>
 <tr><td>How many do you want?</td><td><input type="number" size="12" id="quantity" min="0" alt="marked"></td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<table>
<td>
<b>Choose Extra Toppings($1.75 per topping) </b><br>
<input type=radio name=cheese value=1.75 checked>Extra Cheese<br>
<input type=radio name=pepperoni value=1.75>Pepperoni<br>
<input type=radio name=mushroom value=1.75>Mushrooms<br>
<input type=radio name=bacon value=1.75>Bacon<br>
<input type=radio name=olives value=1.75>Olives<br>
</td>
</table>
</tr>


<table style="width:100%">

<tr valign=top>
<td>
<b>Choose Sandwich <b><br>
<img src="garden.jpg" alt="">
<input type=radio name=sandwichtype value=7.50 checked>All Garden Vegetarian $7.50<br>
<img src="beef.jpg" alt="">
<input type=radio name=sandwichtype value=8.50>Big Beef on a Bun $8.50<br>
<img src="mixedgrill.jpg" alt="">
<input type=radio name=sandwichtype value=9.50>Mixed Grill $9.50<br>
<img src="grilledpork.jpg" alt="">
<input type=radio name=sandwichtype value=9.50>Grilled Pork $9.50<br>
</td>
</table>
<br>
<table>
<br>

 <tr><td>How many do you want?</td><td><input type="number" size="12" id="quantity" min="0"></td></tr>
</table>
<br>

<table>
<td>
<b>Choose Drinks </b><br>
<input type=radio name=drink checked>Cola<br>
<input type=radio name=drink >Orange<br>
<input type=radio name=drink >Lemon<br>
<input type=radio name=drink >Root Beer<br>
</td>
</table>
<br>
<table>
<td>
<b>Choose Size (Small: $1.25, Medium $1.75, Large: $2.00) </b><br>
<input type=radio name=drinkspecialty value=1.25 checked>Small<br>
<input type=radio name=drinkspecialty value=1.75 >Medium<br>
<input type=radio name=drinkspecialty value=2.00 >Large<br>
</td>
</table>

<table>
<br>

 <tr><td>How many do you want?</td><td><input type="number" size="12" id="quantity" min="0"></td></tr>
 
</table>
</tr>

<br>
<br>
<button onclick="buttonandchecks()">Order Menu</button>
<h2>Order Description: </h2><h2><span id="result"></span></h2>
</form>

<h2>This program will set a session cookie and long term cookie</h2>

<form>
<table>
<tr><td>Customer Name: </td><td><input type="text" size="20" id="customername" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Last Visit: </td><td><input type="text" size="20" id="lastvisit" /></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Write Cookies" id="submit" />

</form>

<h2><span id="showcookies"></span>
</h2>

<br>
<h3><span id="showname"></span></h3>
<h3><span id="showaddress"></span></h3>
<h3><span id="showtel"></span></h3>
<br>
<h3><span id="showpizza"></span></h3>
<h3><span id="showtopping"></span></h3>
<h3><span id="showsandwich"></span></h3>
<h3><span id="showsoda"></span></h3>
<h3><span id="showtotal"></span></h3>

<br> 

</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: `I need to check local storage to check if cookies exist` no, localStorage have nothing to do with cookies

Comment: How do I check it then?

Comment: well, what is `$.cookie` - is that some jquery library?

Comment: Yes, it's a jquery cookie

Comment: yeah .. is it the now unmaintained library? - see "docs" - https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie - it shows you how to read a cookie